# Исключение InetAdress.getLocalHost() - UnknownHost

Tags: java, сеть

Мне нужно получить адрес устройства, но этот метод отказывается работать, кидая исключения. Все, что я смог нагуглить, это надо что-то записать в hosts, но не помогло. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решилось созданием блоков try catch.

```
try {
        Println(Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {}
```